# If $S = A\cdot A\cdot A$ generates $G$ and $f(S) = H$ is a group then $f(A) \leqslant H$ is also a group? Under what conditions is this true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, open-problem

Let $G, H$ be two abelian groups and $f : G \to H$ a group homomorphism.  Suppose that $G = \langle S \rangle$ and that $f(S) = H' \leqslant H$ a subgroup.  In that case we say that *$S$ represents $H'$ under $f$.*

Suppose this is true for $S \subset G$ and $f : G \to H$.  Suppose further that $S = A^3 = A\cdot A \cdot A = \{ abc : a,b,c \in A\}$ where multiplication is done in $G$.

Then I want to conclude that $A$ represents a subgroup of $H$ under $f$ as well.

How can we go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}$ (Unless I'm misunderstanding the question) I don't think this is necessarily true. Suppose $G=\ZZ$, $H=\ZZ/3\ZZ$, $f$ is the quotient map, and $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$. Then $S$ generates $G$ and forms a complete residue system modulo $3$, so $f(S)=H$. Now, $S=A\cdot A\cdot A$ where $A=\{0,1\}$, but the image of $A$ is $\{0,1\}$, which is not a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Under what conditions is it true do you think?

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU I'm not sure. I don't have any particular reason to think that there should be such nice conditions. Do you think there should be?

Comment: I happens when you consider fractions $\dfrac{pqr}{stu}$ such that all variables are prime.  Those fractions form $S$ and by Helfgott's Ternary Goldbach Theorem, $f(S) = \Bbb{Z}$ where $f(\dfrac{pqr}{stu}) = p + q + r - s - t - u$.  So that happens in this case, but I guess it's hard to prove that $A = \{ \dfrac{pq}{st}\}$ would represent $\Bbb{Z}$ as well...